# vue-cli with Webpack: how to custom splitting import chunk?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, bundle, chunks

I'm not sure the title is hit the point or not, I'll try my best to explain:

I have 4 pages, which is `a1.vue`, `a2.vue`, `b1.vue` and `b2.vue`
my `router/index.js`:

```
import a1 from '@/components/a1';  
import a2 from '@/components/a2';  
import b1 from '@/components/b1';  
import b2 from '@/components/b2';  

var router = new Router({  
    routes: [{  
        path: '/a1',  
        name: 'name-a1',  
        component: a1  
    }, {  
        path: '/a2',  
        name: 'name-a2',  
        component: a2  
    }, {  
        path: '/b1',  
        name: 'name-b1',  
        component: b1  
    }, {  
        path: '/b2',  
        name: 'name-b2-page',  
        component: b2  
    }]  
});
```

then if I run `npm run build`, it will render a `app.js` file, which include my `a1~b2` pages' resources.
and I know that if I write this:

```
const a1 = ()=> import('@/components/a1');  
const a2 = ()=> import('@/components/a2');  
const b1 = ()=> import('@/components/b1');  
const b2 = ()=> import('@/components/b2');
```

`webpack` will render `a1.js`, `a2.js`, `b1.js`, `b2.js` for me, and only load it when I visit the mapping page.
here is the question:

how to chunk `a.js` and `b.js`,
which `a.js` includes `a1.js` and `a2.js` source,
`b.js` includes `b1.js` and `b2.js` source?
and of course, if I visit `/a2` after visit `/a1`, the `a.js` won't load again.

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use webpack's special parameters via comments feature.

For example, in your case:

```
const a1 = ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "a" */'@/components/a1');
const a2 = ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "a" */'@/components/a2');
const b1 = ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "b" */'@/components/b1');
const b2 = ()=> import(/* webpackChunkName: "b" */'@/components/b2');
```

You also can use `webpackMode: lazy`.

For more info and examples read: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but it making my initial load super slow, Anyone have an idea why?